# All OMA-URI fail and don't work (Google Workspace on Windows 10 Pro)

Tags: windows, google-workspace, mdm

I set up multiple custom settings via OMA-URI on the Google Workspace Admin panel, from inactivity to simple background image changing. But every single one fails for all 13 computers (different types/brands).

All computers running Windows 10 Pro (current updates) except 1 (special computer)

We switched from 2003 AD (removed all computers from the domain) to Google Workspace MDM and everyone can login to the computers via their Google accounts and no issues with that. But not a single OMA-URI is working. I go to audit and ask day every attempt to sync/deploy the settings said "failed" "error 500"

The crazy things, is that 1 of the computers is Windows 11 Pro brand new or off the box yesterday, never joined the AD even, I set up straight to Google MDM and it's also failing. I can't figure out the issue.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

A few things I have encountered, 1 is to make sure that the policies you are applying are actually compatible with Pro. There are some non obvious policies that apply to enterprise and Education only. Second is to make sure your policy path has no trailing or leading spaces. In Google, the policies can autofill and I ALWAYS use that to avoid typing errors.